# PHP - Generator, send does not follow the yield order

Tags: php, generator, yield

I want to write example codes step by step how to separate tasks in a generator and move them into 2 or more generators in order to achieve cooperative multitasking between them. You can find all of my tests about this [here](https://github.com/inf3rno/php-tasks/blob/master/test/integration/CooperativeGeneratorTest55.php).

Generators are logical in some way, but I got stucked by a single step, which I cannot explain why it works this way:

The generator:

```
    $spy = new Object();
    $spy->tasks = array();

    $createGenerator = function ($i1) use ($spy) {

        yield; //(* -> task 1)
        $spy->tasks[] = $i1;
        yield($i1); //(task 1 -> *)

        $i1 = yield; //(* -> task 2)
        //task 2
        $i2 = $i1 + 1;
        $spy->tasks[] = $i2;
        yield($i2); //(task 2 -> *)

        $i2 = yield; //(* -> task 3)
        $i3 = $i2 + 1;
        $spy->tasks[] = $i3;
        yield($i3); //(task 3 -> *)

        $i3 = yield; //(* -> task 4)
        $i4 = $i3 + 1;
        $spy->tasks[] = $i4;
        yield($i4); //(task 4 -> *)

        $i4 = yield; //(* -> task 5)
        $i5 = $i4 + 1;
        $spy->tasks[] = $i5;
        yield($i5); //(task 5 -> *)

    };
```

The test I waited to succeed, but it failed:

```
    /** @var Generator $generator */
    $generator = $createGenerator(1);

    $i1 = $generator->send(null);
    $generator->send($i1);
    $i2 = $generator->send(null);
    $generator->send($i2);
    $i3 = $generator->send(null);
    $generator->send($i3);
    $i4 = $generator->send(null);
    $generator->send($i4);
    $i5 = $generator->send(null);

    $this->assertSame($spy->tasks, array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    $this->assertSame(array($i1, $i2, $i3, $i4, $i5), array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

The test that unexpectedly succeeds:

```
    /** @var Generator $generator */
    $generator = $createGenerator(1);

    $i1 = $generator->send(null);
    $generator->send(null); //blank sends needed to skip the yield-yield gaps
    $i2 = $generator->send($i1);
    $generator->send(null);
    $i3 = $generator->send($i2);
    $generator->send(null);
    $i4 = $generator->send($i3);
    $generator->send(null);
    $i5 = $generator->send($i4);

    $this->assertSame($spy->tasks, array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    $this->assertSame(array($i1, $i2, $i3, $i4, $i5), array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Can you explain me this odd behavior of generators by double `yield`?

**Conclusion:**

The `send()` always runs the code from the input of a `yield` to the output of the next `yield`. So by running a `Generator` with `send()`, it always begins with an input, that's why you cannot get the output of the first `yield` with a `send()`, and that's why you always got a `null` return value by the last `send()`, before the `Generator` goes to an invalid state... Sadly the PHP manual has a lack of this information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Working example

Working example of a generator for your test:

```
$spy = new stdClass();
$spy->tasks = array();

$createGenerator = function ($i1) use ($spy) {
    yield;
    $spy->tasks[] = $i1;
    $i1 = (yield $i1);

    yield;
    $i2 = $i1 + 1;
    $spy->tasks[] = $i2;
    $i2 = (yield $i2);

    yield;
    $i3 = $i2 + 1;
    $spy->tasks[] = $i3;
    $i3 = (yield $i3);

    yield;
    $i4 = $i3 + 1;
    $spy->tasks[] = $i4;
    $i4 = (yield $i4);

    yield;
    $i5 = $i4 + 1;
    $spy->tasks[] = $i5;
    (yield $i5);
};
```

Your test:

```
$generator = $createGenerator(1);

$i1 = $generator->send(null);
$generator->send($i1);
$i2 = $generator->send(null);
$generator->send($i2);
$i3 = $generator->send(null);
$generator->send($i3);
$i4 = $generator->send(null);
$generator->send($i4);
$i5 = $generator->send(null);

print_r($spy);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; ++$i) {
    echo ${'i'.$i} . "\n";
}
```

This gives the desired result:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [tasks] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
        )

)
1
2
3
4
5
```

## Further hints

See [the manual on the send method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/generator.send.php) for further information, which sums up all there is to say about how `send` works:

> Sends the given value to the generator as the result of the current
>   yield expression and resumes execution of the generator.
>
> If the generator is not at a yield expression when this method is
>   called, it will first be let to advance to the first yield expression
>   before sending the value.

You should already know what `yield` does.

To fully understand the interaction between the generator and your test, it should help you to write down (with a pen on a piece of paper) each step in the execution flow of your source code.

### Little note concerning syntax

Also notice the caution box on [yield in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php):

> Caution
>
> If you use yield in an expression context (for example, on the
>   right hand side of an assignment), you must surround the yield
>   statement with parentheses. For example, this is valid:
>
> $data = (yield $value);
>
> But this is not, and will result in a parse error:
>
> $data = yield $value;
>
> This syntax may be used in conjunction with the
>   Generator::send() method.

Comment: Please add general rules about how the `send()` and `yield` work together!

Comment: I have provided a generator, which fulfills your test, and provided some hints, which should help you understand what to look for in understanding the code.

Comment: I already understood, but I wanted a detailed answer for the case somebody has the same problem... :-)
It's funny that we think totally different, I mean by the example I would have added one more `yield` at the beginning and one more `send(null)`, and it would have worked as well... 

It is important to understand, that `send()` runs the code from the input of a `yield` until the output of the next `yield`, and it always begins with an input, that's why you cannot get the first `yield`'s output with a `send()`. Hmm I think I'll add this part to the question as a conclusion.

Comment: You use a local variable for storing tasks, which you got from your local scope? You insert tasks into the generator, just to get them back again? I seriously do not understand, in which situation your generator would help easing any task related problem. My stomach tells me that you want to implement a class instead of a generator as [a generator is just "an easy way to implement simple iterators without the overhead or complexity of implementing a class that implements the Iterator interface."](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php).

Comment: Since I do not understand your use case I would not expect someone to understand it, who did not even understand how generators work... a detailed answer here would make sense if the example were more demonstrative :/

Comment: "You use a local variable for storing tasks, which you got from your local scope?" - This can be just a transient state of code while refactoring it...

Answer (score 2):

This has confused me for several hours now, but I've managed to find out what exactly is going on and how `send` works. The important conclusions are:

- Whether you're sending to (via `send`) or reading from (via `foreach` or `current()`) the Generator first, **it will run to the first `yield` to get "initialised"** and then perform your send/receive at that `yield`. If your first operation is calling `next()`, it will run all the way to the second `yield`.
- Every additional `yield` will be **both the exit and entry point** for the next read/send operation.
- And finally: `send()` performs **both a send and a read operation in that order**, regardless of what you do with the result. This means when you call `send()`, the Generator will move to the next `yield` while handling your call.

With this in mind, let's walk through your test:

1. `$createGenerator(1)` just makes the generator and doesn't run anything, as expected.
2. `$i1 = $generator->send(null);` performs a send first, then a read:

   - The Generator runs until it finds the first `yield`.
   - The `null` you sent is this `yield`'s value if you were to assign it.
   - The Generator continues running to the next `yield`, adding `$i1` to your task list and then handing execution back, with the yielded value `1`.
   - In your test code, this yielded value is assigned to `$i1`.
3. `$generator->send($i1);` now sends this value back into the Generator, again performing a send, then advancing the Generator to the next `yield`, and reading the yielded value:

   - **We're still at the `yield($i1);`**, which previously provided the value `1`. This was the exit point and now becomes the entry point receiving the sent value (**second conclusion above**).
   - However, you're not assigning the value, so the Generator continues to the next `yield`.
   - The next `yield` doesn't provide a value, so `null` is yielded.
   - This isn't assigned in your test code anyway, so everything is fine from the outside view, but inside the Generator, **the sent `1` was discarded rather than stored**.
4. `$i2 = $generator->send(null);` now sends in a `null`, which again results in a send and read operation, in that order, advancing the Generator in the process:

   - `$i1 = yield; //(* -> task 2)` is the current `yield`, which was previously the exit point and now becomes the entry point. **Since we just sent in `null`, that's what is stored in `$i1`**.
   - The Generator now advances, storing `null + 1` (so `1`) in `$i2`, storing that in your task list and then yielding it.
   - This yielded `1` is now stored in your test code's `$i2`. At this point, the previous mistake has leaked out into the test code.
5. This continues on for the rest of the test, so every step will send in the `1`, which will be discarded by the `yield` statement that sent it out, then the next `yield` will store the `null` you send in next and repeat everything. Your resulting array will be `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

Your working test works because it moves the sent value one step further, to the `yield` that actually stores what you send. @GhostGambler's Generator works for the opposite reason, it moves the assignment inside your Generator one step closer, to the `yield` that actually receives the value from your test code.

To illustrate these inner workings, consider the following adapted example:

```
$createGenerator = function ($i) {

    $in1 = yield("out".$i++); //(* -> task 1)
    echo "in1: $in1";
    $in2 = yield("out".$i++); //(task 1 -> *)
    echo "in2: $in2";
    $in3 = yield("out".$i++); //(* -> task 2)
    echo "in3: $in3";
    $in4 = yield("out".$i++); //(task 2 -> *)
    echo "in4: $in4";
    echo "\nGenerator done with i=$i";
};

$generator = $createGenerator(1);

$out = $generator->send("in1");
echo "\nout1: ";var_dump($out);
$out = $generator->send("in2");
echo "\nout2: ";var_dump($out);
$out = $generator->send("in3");
echo "\nout3: ";var_dump($out);
$out = $generator->send("in4");
echo "\nout4: ";var_dump($out);
```

Which creates the following output:

```
in1: in1
out1: string(4) "out2"
in2: in2
out2: string(4) "out3"
in3: in3
out3: string(4) "out4"
in4: in4
Generator done with i=5
out4: NULL
```

Notice that "out1" (the first yielded value) is never captured because the first operation on the Generator is a send. Consequently, the last read operation fails because the Generator only yields 4 values and we're trying to access the fifth yielded value (since we implicitly discarded the first).

One last gotcha is `next()`, which is implicitly called at the end of each iteration of a `foreach` loop. That one is essentially identical to `send(null)`: It sends nothing into the Generator, makes it run to the next `yield`, and discards the next yielded value (although in a `foreach` loop, `current()` is then also called to pick that discarded value up and store it inside the `as` variable). This makes it rather tricky to use `send()` inside a `foreach`.